# Input emojis in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, emoji

I'm puzzled:

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04.5 - and I swear **I saw a 2y old kid accidentally spawn an emoji-input option in something like Mousepad**. The emojis shown in a table were black/white font-ish, not colored bitmaps.

To be honest, I don't recall which editor exactly - but I cannot find out how that kid has done that. I can't find any information about a keyboard shortcut that would do that.

I'm very sure it wasn't any web-browser. ;)

Does anyone have an idea about an emoji-input-option like that, installed by default?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nmath it's good, but for simpler approach, I think using app finder, and just type crtl+dot, and emoji pop up shown, and just copy paste to any location you need.

Comment: @Nmath and Input elector to iBus seems nice also, built in

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!
Yes, "Ctrl+." (control+dot) pops up a monochrome emoji picker (at least in Mousepad) :P :D

I'm curious:
How come some edit fields support "CtrlDot", some don't?
Like: Can't do it here in Firefox or vim, but in most (libgnome-?)applications? (<- Or shall I as that in another question?)